# SQL Select - Current Date - 7 Year

Tags: sql

Hi I am trying to get (current Datetime - Years).

Below is my Query..

```
 print getdate()
 print (getdate()-(365.25*7))
 Result:
 Dec 30 2013 10:47AM
 Dec 30 2006  4:52PM
```

is giving correct result.

But When i try

```
 print getdate()
 print (getdate()-year(7))
 Result:
 Dec 30 2013 10:52AM
 Oct 17 2008 10:52AM
```

Can anyone please tell what is wrong in it?

Comment: Among other things, the Gregorian calendar commonly used by most of the world has a length of 365. **2425** days - you're off by a bit (granted, probably not noticeable over 7 years).  The real problem is that you're doing a blanket subtraction of days, when whether you need to subtract 365/366 days is determined not only by the current year, but _when **during** the year_ it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
print getdate()
print DATEADD(Year, -7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather use [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) with the datepart set to `YEAR`.

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed
>   integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

Something like

```
SELECT GETDATE() Today, DATEADD(YEAR,-7,GETDATE()) Today7YearsAgo
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27374)

The `year(7)` part return `1900`, which is the year part of `1900-01-08 00:00:00.000` (`CAST(7 AS DATETIME)`). Then `getdate()-year(7)` equates to `getdate()-1900`, which is a day subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Try MSSQL [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function

```
select DATEADD(Year,-7,GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

DATE ADD() Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

```
print getdate()
print DATEADD(Year, -7, GETDATE())
```